# How can I filter specific fields in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

How can I filter specific fields in Google Data Studio? I found the option to add filtering only to the entire table.

For example, I have a table with the field `Deals` that can take values "*Closed Lost*", "*Closed Won*" and "*others*". There is also the field `Date of Creation`. Can I somehow depict on one graph the ***metrics***: number of "*Closed Lost*" deals and the number of "*Closed Won*" deals per month?

I found the opportunity to aggregate specific fields but didn't find the opportunity to filter the specific fields and display them in one graphic.

I also considered the option to create a specific *View* (in BigQuery) to display that table but thought that maybe it is possible in Google Data Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a `REGEXP_MATCH` function to create two new fields, one for `Closed Lost` and `Closed Won`. Here's how I would do it:

1. Create a new field called `Closed Lost` and use this formula:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Deals, "Closed Lost") THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

2. Create a new field called `Closed Won` and use this formula:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Deals, "*****Closed Won*****") THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

3. Create a Table with `Date of Creation` as your dimension
4. Add in New fields (`Closed Lost + Closed Won`) as Metrics with the aggregation being `SUM`

That should add up separately all of the individual closed lost and closed won's

***** Make Sure this segment lines up exactly with how it is spelled in your table. If not, it will result in 0's.

Comment: Thank you! Will try this tomorrow!

Comment: Saw your comment below. Make sure the field in your CASE statement is spelled exactly as it is spelled in your table. If not, it will result in 0's.

Comment: I think that it is spelled correctly, because when I select aggregation type COUNT the graphic is built and it is the same as Total deals. So just SUM doesn't work properly, and I don't know why :(

Comment: When I am adding the scorecard of the closed lost deals it depicts properly. The problem is that when I am trying to devide it by months, count works properly but sum doesn't. I don't know the reason...

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it seems that it doesn't work. I used this expression:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Deal_stage, "9 Closed Won (Sales Pipeline)") THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

I then applied the aggregation `SUM`. In this case, the line is at zero. Here what I got:

[image]

In case I choose aggregation type `COUNT` - it simply counts all 1 and 0 values and shows the same graph as with all deals.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why the `SUM` was not calculated properly. The right expression looks like:

```
CASE
  WHEN Deals IN ("Closed Lost") THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to create a blended data source. Basically you take a data source and drag the fields in you want to use and add the filters. Then you can blend the data source with it again and the same fields and add different filters. Make sure to name fields differently otherwise you will get duplicate field names.
This will give you a new data source in the drop down named whatever you wish and will allow you to add individual fields on to the chart that are all separately filtered.

Blended Data Example:

[image]

[Here is Google's help documentation on blended data](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420?hl=en)